# How to open in an existing ViewController from a WKWebView link?

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I have a WKWebView with 3 links, I want each one to redirect to a different ViewController, but I'm a novice in swift 3, and the answers I found do not understand how to use them.

This is what I find:

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView,
    shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest,
    navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

    if navigationType == .linkClicked{
        if let url = URL(string:"YourURLString") {
            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url){
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
                return false
            }
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't check it but it should work

```
if navigationType == .linkClicked{
    if let url = URL(string:"YourURLString") {
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url){
            let controller = MyCustomController()
            self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

But I need to say that it's very bad practice to control your app from webview...

Comment: Why `UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)` while you're not opening the link outside the application?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, the links in the WebView are because there is a 3D model. I had never done an app with swift and investigating what I managed to do.

But I do not know how to implement your code, is it inside the override func viewDidLoad ()?, Or do I have to add some Javascript function to receive the instruction?

Thanks for your valuable comments !!!

Comment: Until now, I added a Javascript function in the HTML that sends "#DT-1" or "#PH-2" depending on the link, but I do not know if Swift takes it that way to open its ViewController